# What is the difference between initializing struct in following ways in C?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am learning c. I have an struct that looks like below. I see 2 different ways of initializing the struct variable. It would be great, if someone could explain what is the difference between these 2 ways & which one is preferred in which case.

```
typedef struct {
  int length;
  int* elements;
} Array;

Array create_array_type_one(int size) {
  
  Array result;
  
  result.length = 0;
  result.elements = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
  
  return result;
  
}

Array* create_array_type_two(int size) {
  
  Array *array = (Array *) malloc(sizeof(Array));
  
  array->length = 0;
  array->elements = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
  
  return array;
  
}
```

Comment: Generally, passing and `return`ing a `struct`'s address is preferable as it doesn't require copying data to the stack.

Comment: @FiddlingBits, thanks for the feedback. I have an another doubt. In the first type of initializing, memory for elements are allocated in heap. So, if simply `Array` is passed around instead of the address`Array*`, will those elements also be copied to stack?

Comment: No, just the address of those elements.

Comment: @FiddlingBits, oh I see, thanks!

Comment: @FiddlingBits, if you can post your comments as answer, that'd be great.

Comment: You might want to use [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) and you should read both [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: Neither is preferred. use FMA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here we are talking about **STRUCTURES & FUNCTIONS**.

Basically there are three methods by which invoker and invoked structure function can communicate to each other.

> 1. Passing each member of the structure as an actual argument of the function call, or returning to the each member type.
> 2. Sending the copy of the structure to the entire called function or returning to the struct type (call by value).
> 3. Using pointers, pass the structure as an argument and indirectly work on the original structure or returning the address of the struct (call by reference).

Your, **CASE 1:**

```
Array create_array_type_one(int size) {
  
  Array result;
  
  result.length = 0;
  result.elements = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
  
  return result;
  
}
```

In this case you are **`returning`** a copy of the entire structure to the calling function. So, in order to use it in your `main()` function, you should do something like this:

```
Array new;
new = create_array_type_one(5);
```

Here, you are assigning the returned structure of type `Array` to a structure of type `Array`.

In **CASE 2:**

```
Array* create_array_type_two(int size) {
  
  Array *array = (Array *) malloc(sizeof(Array));
  
  array->length = 0;
  array->elements = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
  
  return array;
  
}
```

In this case you are using pointers and returning a pointer to the newly created data structure of type `Array`. You are not sending a copy of the structure to the calling function instead you are sending its address to the calling function. Therefore, what happening in the `main()` while calling like this is:

```
Array *ptr;
ptr = create_array_type_two(5);
```

Both cases has there own advantages and disadvantages like CASE 1 ensures data safety as all the work done by the called function happens on a copy  but uses extra memory. Where CASE 2 is more efficient and faster as compared to the previous method, as it uses same memory location for the operation.

Answer (score 1):

The difference of them is the return type.
create_array_type_one() returns Array type memory location.
create_array_type_two() returns a pointer to Array type memory location.

As Array type has only two elements, int and int *, the size difference between two of them is not big . So you can use anyone for your coding preference in this case.
I'd like to recommend you the second one if the size of structure is kind of big...